# having problems understanding this SQL Syntax

Tags: sql

I am having a problem understanding this query syntax:

```
SELECT p.id, p.ProductName, p.Color, psl.Price, psl.Quantity, psl.Discount
```

What does `psl` stands for? I haven't been able to find explanation elsewhere. (Sorry if the question is stupid or on the wrong forum, I've been coding for 21 hours in a row :( )

Comment: You are missing the `FROM` clause for this `SELECT` statement. `p` is a table alias from where the data is being selected. Refer this : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Comment: where are your tables?

Comment: zsn, it sounds like your a very new to SQL and people on SO can be very condescending hence the down votes. To put what your asking in terms of other languages, it's like you just asked a question on a Hello World program. Basic SELECT statements  are the first thing you learn in SQL. I would recommend if you want to learn, try W3schools(the link Saagar provided). They are a nice reference. If you really want to learn SQL, Head First has the best beginners book for SQL that I've seen and it's not a super dry like most technical books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The psl is an alias for said table, rather than forcing your syntax to be the full name of the table.

Answer (score 3):

Those appear to be aliases for the actual table name and should be specified in your FROM and/or JOIN clauses. For instance, a complete query with that syntax might be:

```
SELECT p.id, p.ProductName, p.Color, psl.Price, psl.Quantity, psl.Discount  
FROM MyDatabase.dbo.SomeTableName AS p
JOIN MyDatabase.dbo.ARelatedTable AS psl
    ON p.id = psl.pid
WHERE p.id = 12345
```